Extrcating Body Request. ( Data Exfiltration Detection )
I am working on a detecting data exfiltration for am android malware. I noticed it makes some post request to the server. I have downloaded the AOSP and modified the Request.java and HttpEngine.java (sendRequest function). All i am seeing is the

11-21 01:27:26.124  2976  3107 I System.out: NetworkInterceptor - Request Body: com.android.okhttp.RequestBody$2@dbb88bc

The body like this. Is there a way i can get the request body in clear text?
I wanted to detect what kind of data is being submitted to the server form victims device. I am working on a behavioral analysis engine for malware detection

Looks like you're just logging a RequestBody instance directly. You need to instead parse and log the contents from it.
Check the contentType to make sure the type is text and get the charset from it. Then use the charset to convert the content to readable text. For example, given byte[] contents, if the charset is UTF_8 you can do new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).
But if the malware isn't actually sending the data as clear text, this won't help.

I tried to include a default application Interceptor to every instance of the OKHTTP in OKHTTPClient.java file.
public OkHttpClient() {
routeDatabase = new RouteDatabase();
dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
// Add the CustomLoggingInterceptor by default
this.interceptors.add(new CustomLoggingInterceptor());
}
Interceptor is initialized when application creates a object of okhhtp class but it doesnot log any data.
Log: NetworkInterceptor2 - LoggingInterceptor: Custom Logger Initialized
